# Why do I have an undefined variable warning whenever I register but still saves the data?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have `maiden name` textbox field that will be enable only if the gender is Female and status of the user is NOT single, but whenever a user registers with a single status, that's when the warning comes out, but it still saves the data. Why and how can I remove that warning message since it is visible while the message echos.

My html code:

```
<label> Maiden Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="maiden" id="mySelect" value="" disabled=true placeholder="Maiden Nname" onKeyPress="return ValidateAlpha(event);" onblur="toUpper(this.value, this.id);" >

<label>Gender</label>
       <input type=radio name="gender" id="gender" value='Male'>&nbsp;Male &nbsp;
       <input type=radio name="gender" id="gender" value='Female'>&nbsp;Female 

<label>Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Married">Married</option>
        <option value="Widow">Widow</option>
    </select>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
<script>
    //whenever an item with the name attribute set to gender or status is changed:
    $(document).on("change", "[name=gender],[name=status]", function(){
        //gather the checked gender
        var gender = $('[name=gender]:checked').val();
      //gather the selected status
      var status = $('[name=status] option:selected').val();
      //if the user checked female and selected single
      if(gender == 'Female' && status != 'Single'){
        //enable the maidenname input
        $('[name=maiden]').prop('disabled', false);
      }
     else{
        //disable the maidenname input
        $('[name=maiden]').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
</script>
```

My php

```
<?php
include('dbcontroller.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $gender = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['gender']));
    $status = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['status']));
    $maiden = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['maiden']));

    $query = "INSERT INTO requests(gender, status, maiden) VALUES('$gender','$status','$maiden')";
 }   ?>
```

Comment: It would help to see your code, there is nothing we can do until you share it... It's like saying I have coded a cup blue, how do I change it to red? & you show us no code.

Comment: i've posted my code sir @KyleE4K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be specific without your code, and generally you'll want to post actual errors too,   but it sounds like you need...

```
 if(empty($_POST['maidenname'])) {$_POST['maidenname'] ='';}
```

Comment: i will try that sir! :)